# Recreating an Activity and saving values

Tags: java, android

I wanna recreate activity with saving one int value. I don't know why onSavedInstance always has value `null`:

```
    public class ActionActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
//...
int p = 0;
String newString;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.action);
        progress = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Progress);
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            p = savedInstanceState.getInt("PROGRESS");
        }
        p++;
        newString = String.valueOf(p);
        progress.setText(newString);

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActionActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    savedInstanceState.putInt("PROGRESS", p);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState); }
}
```

Comment: My guess is that you have a misunderstanding of what "recreate" means. What _exactly_ are you trying to do? Do you want this `int` to be saved when you re-start the app?

Comment: I want to save this value when I restart **activity** (not app at all). This activity calls `ActionActivity` and in `onClick()` method I call this `ActionActivity` again.

Comment: `onSaveInstanceState()` is called when an activity is "destroyed and recreated", which means a very specific thing. The most common scenarios where this happens is when the user rotates their device or when the user puts your app in the background. This does *not* happen if the user opens your activity, goes back, and then opens your activity again.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I understand you. Then is there a way to save int value while recalling same activity? I know about `putExtra()` for different activities, but don't sure if this works on same activity...